# Create pandas column with best match lookup

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find an efficient way to find the best match in a lookup table. By best match I mean find the longest possible exact match in the the lookup table for the values in the data table.

My lookup table contains values `['A', 'A1', 'A12']`. With data values `['A', 'B', 'A1', 'A2', 'A12', 'A13', 'A123', 'A132']` the result should be `['A', NaN, 'A1', 'A', 'A12', 'A1', 'A12', 'A1']`.

The following code loops through all possible lengths of the lookup keys (1, 2, and 3 in the above example), creates `key_1` as the first n characters of column `A` and finds the matches in the `lookup` table.

It works, but I am sure there is a more elegant solution.

```py
import pandas as pd

lookup = pd.DataFrame({'Cat': ['A', 'A1', 'A12']} )
print("Lookup table: \n", lookup, "\n")
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'A1', 'A2', 'A12', 'A13', 'A123', 'A132']})
print("Data table: \n", data, '\n---')

key_lengths = lookup['Cat'].str.len().drop_duplicates().sort_values().values
#key_lengths = [1]
for c in key_lengths:
    data['key_1'] = data['A'].str.slice(0, c)
    data = data.merge(lookup, left_on=['key_1'], right_on=['Cat'], how='left')
    idx = data['Cat'].notnull()
    data.loc[idx, 'Category'] = data.loc[idx, 'Cat']
    data.drop('Cat', axis=1, inplace=True)


data.drop('key_1', axis=1, inplace=True)
print("Result:\n", data)
```

The results of the code is

```
Lookup table: 
    Cat
0    A
1   A1
2  A12 

Data table: 
       A
0     A
1     B
2    A1
3    A2
4   A12
5   A13
6  A123
7  A132 
---
Result:
       A Category
0     A        A
1     B      NaN
2    A1       A1
3    A2        A
4   A12      A12
5   A13       A1
6  A123      A12
7  A132       A1
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sort the lookup values list by `len` from longest to shortest, and join it to a string pattern `'(A12|A1|A)'`. Finally, using `str.extract` on this pattern.

```
l = ['A', 'A1', 'A12']
l = sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)

Out[239]: ['A12', 'A1', 'A']

p = '('+'|'.join(l)+')'
data['Category'] = data['A'].str.extract(p)

Out[255]:
      A Category
0     A        A
1     B      NaN
2    A1       A1
3    A2        A
4   A12      A12
5   A13       A1
6  A123      A12
7  A132       A1
```